# Fill vector with constructor call

Tags: c++, c++11, move-constructor

I have two classes, one derive from the other.  I would like to allocate an `std:vector` which is fill of the derived class.  The tricky question is that I want it to call the move constructor written in the base class.

Here is the code:

```
class Base{
    public:
    size_t size;
    double* buff;

    Base(size_t _size):size(_size){
        buff = new double[size];
    }

    Base() = delete;
    Base operator=(const Base&) = delete;
    Base(const Base&) = delete;

    Base(Base&& b):size(b.size), buff(b.buff){
        b.buff = nullptr;
    }
    Base operator=(Base&& b){
        size = b.size;
        buff = b.buff;
        b.buff = nullptr;
    }
};

class Derive : public Base{
    public:
    Derive(size_t _size):Base(_size){};
    Derive() = delete;
    Derive operator=(const Derive&) = delete;
    Derive(const Derive&) = delete;

    Derive(Derive&& b):Base(move(b)){}
    Derive operator=(Derive&& b){
        Base::operator=(move(b));
    }
};

/********/

vector<Derive> v(10, move(Derive(5)));
```

g++ is telling me

```
error: use of deleted function ‘Derive::Derive(const Derive&)’
 { ::new(static_cast<void*>(__p)) _T1(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
```

and I don't understand what I am supposed to do.

Comment: Btw, you should also reset `B::size` upon being moved from, not just `B::buff`.

Comment: Why don't you use std::vector in Base for buff?

Comment: Slightly OT… assignment operators should always return a reference to `*this`. Yours have undefined behavior (if they even compile).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is that `std::vector(count, object)` **copies** `object`, `count` times, into the vector.  You cannot move from it since you can only move an object into a single object.

If your class is not copyable then you will not be able to use it.  You can however use

```
std::vector<Type> foo;
foo.reserve(count);
for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    foo.emplace_back(Types_parmeters);
```

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to build a vector of 10 elements from one single source. This is not possible because once the source element has been moved once, it is left in an undeterminated state.

For that reason, this constructor is specified in draft n4296 for C++14 to use the copy constructor (emphasize mine):

> 23.3.6.2 vector constructors, copy, and assignment [vector.cons]
>   
> ...
> `vector(size_type n, const T& value,
>   const Allocator& = Allocator());`
>   Effects: Constructs a vector with n copies of value, using the specified allocator.
>   Requires: **T shall be CopyInsertable** into *this.
>   ...

Comment: one could still copy (and even move from) the "undeterminated" state – it's not invalid, but it's not what presumably was intended.

Comment: @Walter: but the standard is clear: T must be CopyInsertable and the copy ctor is deleted...

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution is to write your own version of `fill_n` that can handle this use case. The typical `fill_n` does copies the same as the vector constructor, but we can write a more modern style one.

```
template <class T, class OutputIt, class Size, class .. Args>
OutputIt emplace_fill_n(OutputIt first, Size count, const Args& ... args)
{
    for (Size i = 0; i != count; ++i) {
        *first = T(args...);
        ++first;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
vector<Derive> v();
v.reserve(10);
emplace_fill_n<Derive>(back_inserter(v), 10);
```